# Choosing a test based on by data and how to test when I have several groups?

Tags: correlation, exploratory-data-analysis

I'm trying to analyze the effect of the laying order on a certain concentration of immune factor. I have a large set of data (1000+ eggs). I want to know if egg 1 (first-laid egg) will have higher concentrations than the last-laid egg (egg 7, 8, 9, etc) or even if the concentrations tend to increase/decrease with laying order. I have no idea where to start and I think I'm confusing myself because I'm looking at several nests to see if the effect happens in most cases. If anyone could help me out,  or even give me a push in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Some of my data looks like this:

[image]

Comment: First you should start of with some **Exploratory Data Analysis**--that will give you the push you need... Is the data available online in an easily accessible format (such as **.csv**)? Because if you gave a link then I (or someone else) could take a look at it...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5do0vcqSzElRHlMbjVlZGZBUUU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Does that link work?

Comment: Yeah, I see it--it all looks pretty homogeneous but that may change with more data--how much more data do you have? ... It's possible that the variance of the concentration decreases slightly as egg number increases--that's definitely a potential path that I'd pursue further.

Comment: I have about another 1000 eggs, all grouped like the data I sent, in multiple nests. I'm really new to statistics. I've taken only 2 classes, one about 5 years ago and another basic one a few months ago. I've even been reading several articles on how to get started and choosing the correct test, but I really can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: As a side note, next time don't put spaces in between your columns when you upload a dataset--it actually kind of messes with the data-loading process...

Comment: I've made a scatterplot with about half of the data. It doesn't seem to have a noticeable pattern.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5do0vcqSzElZ3V1UjFvVHdQYzA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What's the deal with egg #438? Also, could you please give a little more context--did you collect the data yourself? Is it possible that there could be transcription errors in the dataset?

Comment: I collected this data myself by running an assay of the samples. These values are the average of 3 replicates. No dilutions were done which is why the values are so low. I'm not sure what you mean for egg 438. The value I have is 0.010889. It is not likely that there are transcription errors. There hasn't been a lot of research done on this subject, especially on this species, which is why there may only be a pattern with a few consecutive eggs or there may not even be a pattern at all.